# Git SSH not working in SSH session

Tags: ssh, git

First of all, I am not entirely sure if this is a problem with Ubuntu itself, but any insight would be helpful. I use Ubuntu 14.04. I have a git repo cloned over SSH, and normally I have no problems using it. But if I SSH into my machine, I am not able to reach the github server anymore.

[image]

Comment: How do you authenticate to the github?

Comment: I have added my public key to my github account.

Comment: If you are using ssh-agent to store the publickey with which you authenticate to github on your GUI login, you need to ensure you have access to the same keys on an ssh login.  What happens if you `ssh -A santhosh@localhost` , for example?

Comment: That actually works! Could you tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably you are using key stored in some non-standard location and added to your `gnome-keyring`.

Using `ssh -A santhosh@localhost` will forward the connection to your agent and you will be able to use the same identity withing ssh session.

Other way would be to specify the identity file in your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host github.com
  IdentityFile path/to/key
```

Comment: Is there a way to find the key file that is currently being used?

Comment: When you open `seahorse` (`gnome-keyring`), you should see what keys are added there.